# How can I convert a base64 image into a MediaStream that is usable in a <video> .srcObject Attribute?

Tags: javascript, stream

I am trying to turn base64 images (which I'm receiving from a server) into a MediaStream that I can define as the .srcObject of a `<video>` element (I need it in a `<video>` element so that I can use it properlly in as an aframe-asset).

I tried:

- just setting it as .src or .srcObject
- using fetch to get a stream
- converting that stream into a mediastream using `new MediaStream()`

An ideal solution for me would be that I first generate a stream and then push to it or similar.